# target Audience in MOSS2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, target-audience

Well done on the great postings!

I have a query:

How can I add a single name/user/person in the target audience field of MOSS2007?

Currenlty I am only allowed to add a MOSS group.

However, many times there are a number of individual persons (that are in the same group) that I would like to add as audience.

Answer (score 0):

Moss doesn't allow adding person in audience target. We can add only group. So create a group and add the person in that group. After that you can give the group name as target audience.

Comment: Thank you Hojo.

There is no work-around for this?

The only solution is to create groups with a sinlge name/person in it?